# How to identify an android emulator using ADB

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator, adb, bluestacks

I'm studying the ADB commands using an android emulator called MEmuPlay. I got it working with one emulator running, I could start and connect to the device and send some commands using adb.exe

The problem now is when I open 2+ emulators, when I run "adb devices" I can see all emulators, but I can't identify which device in that list is MEmu_1 or MEmu_2 or Bluestacks.

There is a way to maybe create an alias to X device based in the process ID or something that I can know exactly which device I want to send messages? OR maybe force it to have an specific name in that device list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers after `emulator-` in the `adb devices` output are `TCP` ports those emulator instances are *listening* at for the `adb` commands.

You have not provided much information about your specific environment, so I would keep my answer pretty generic as well.

In order to associate an emulator instance (identified by a name provided as a command line parameter during start or a window title at runtime) with a `TCP` port number that instance is listening at you just need to cross-link the outputs of `ps` and `netstat` in a *unix* based environment or `tasklist` and `netstat in a *windows* environment by *process ID* column.